# fs.readFileSync fails while using sudo in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, fs

I am trying to read a file in node.  It works fine with a normal node execution, but for this test I require `sudo` so I can access port 443.

Here is a simple test  `tester.js`:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFileSync('./tester.js', {encoding: 'utf-8'});

console.log('Works!');
```

This code works for:

```
$ node tester.js     
Works!
```

When running with sudo it yields an error.

```
sudo node tester.js

buffer.js:440
      throw new Error('Unknown encoding');
            ^
Error: Unknown encoding
    at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:440:13)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:236:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tester.js:3:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:245:9)
```

Node Version: v0.10.26

Ubuntu Ver  : 14.04 LTS

This code works on other people's machines, its specific to me.

Comment: Try upgrading to Node v0.12.

Comment: Just used `nvm` to pull down 0.12.7 and it still fails.

Comment: Do `node -v` to be sure (i.e. did you `nvm use 0.12`?)